# My Program Creates 1 Ball not 2

Tags: coordinates, public

I made a program that creates a frame and then creates 2 balls and moves them around seperately, my problem is that somehow the first or second ball is getting the coordinates of the other, and therefore are being painted on each other, sorry for the bad indentation this is my first time posting a question .

Main Class:

```
    public class Game extends JPanel {
        Ball ball01 = new Ball();
        Ball ball02 = new Ball();
        int ball01x = 0,ball01y = 0,ball02x = 0,ball02y = 0;
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fillOval(ball01x, ball01y, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(ball02x, ball02y, 10, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Frame");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.createBalls();
        while (true) {
            game.getCoords();
            game.updateBalls();
            game.repaint();
            System.out.println("Ball01 x: " + game.ball01x + " Ball02 x " + game.ball02x);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    public void getCoords(){
        ball01x = ball01.getX();
        ball01y = ball01.getY();
        ball02x = ball02.getX();
        ball02y = ball02.getY();
    }

    public void createBalls(){
        ball01.create(300,300);
        ball02.create(50,20);
    }

    public void updateBalls(){
        ball01.Ball();
        ball02.Ball();
    }
}
```

Ball Class:

```
public class Ball{
    private static int x;
    private static int y;
    private static int xSize = 30;
    private static int ySize = 30;
    static boolean xright = true,ydown = true;   
    static boolean grow = false;
    public void Ball(){
        this.moveBall();
        this.ballSize();
    }

    public void create(int startX, int startY){
        this.x = startX;
        this.y = startY;
    }

    private void moveBall() {
        if(this.x >= 370){
            xright = false;  
        }
        if(this.x <= 0){
            xright = true;
        }
        if(this.y >= 370){
            ydown = false;
        }
        if(this.y < 0){
            ydown = true;
        }

        if(xright == true){
            this.x = this.x + 1;
        }else if (xright == false){
            this.x = this.x - 1;
        }

        if(ydown == true){
            this.y = this.y + 1;
        }else if (ydown == false){
            this.y = this.y - 1;
        }

    }

    private void ballSize(){
        if (xSize <= 5 && ySize <= 5){
            grow = true;
        }else if (xSize >= 10 && ySize >= 10){
            grow = false;
        }

        if (grow == true){
            xSize = xSize + 1;
            ySize = ySize + 1;
            //System.out.println("Debug");
        }else if (grow == false){
            xSize--;
            ySize--;
            //System.out.println("Debug");
        }
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because your coordinate variables are `static`. You don't want instance-specific properties to be static. [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx). In simple words, such properties are "global" and have one value.

Comment: Thank you so much! Taking off the static from each variable worked perfectly, thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO :)